# bootstrap toggle checkbox button label changed by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change label of toggle button with data-on and data-off style.
How can I do it?
My toggle create as under html.

Sending OnSending Off

I've created button as under js code:

```
 $("#allOnOff").bootstrapToggle({   
  on            :   "Sending On",
  off           :   "Sending Off",
  onstyle       :   "success",
  offstyle      :   "danger"        
 });
```

And I need to change it as under:

```
$("#allOnOff").bootstrapToggle({
  on            :   "Custom",
  off           :   "Sending Off",
  onstyle       :   "warning",
  offstyle      :   "danger"
 });
```

But it's not make any changes. Please help.

Comment: Please add your HTML here

Comment: <input type="checkbox" id="allOnOff" data-toggle="toggle" checked class="emailOnOff" data-size="normal" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-on="Sending On" data-off="Sending Off"></th>

Answer (score 1):

As you are changing label from **JS** you don't need to put that in **HTML**. You should replace your **HTML** with below code::

```
<input type="checkbox" id="allOnOff" data-toggle="toggle" checked class="emailOnOff" data-size="normal" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
```

And keep your **JS** code as it is.

Working **JSFIDDLE LINK**:: https://jsfiddle.net/cswuL90j/